# problem using aws-cli s3 sync command object acl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I Had transfer files from Source S3 account to Destination account S3 using cli. Unfortunately I used a user in source account with proper permissions to upload files in destination. All files synced properly but the problem is ACl.. the objects in destination have source account ownership. now I want to change ownership or read/write permissions to destination account. i tried all ways but I could not find any usefull solution. Please let me know the proper solution?.
Thanks in advance.. and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use credentials from the source account owner to add the bucket-owner-full-control ACL to the objects.

Comment: agree w/ jarmod -- see an example here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/

Comment: thanks jarmod  & Elinda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the destination account, set S3 Object Ownership on the destination bucket to bucket owner preferred. After you set S3 Object Ownership, new objects uploaded with the access control list (ACL) set to bucket-owner-full-control are automatically owned by the bucket's account.

Go through this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

it has solution for your problem

you need to modify the destination bucket policy

Comment: Great to hear that !!. If it helps you please accept the answer so it will help others in future for similar issues